# How to extrude an SVG but not equally?

Tags: modeling, extrude, svg

I have a flat SVG imported right now. This shape has some kind of spikes on the edges (highlighted them with yellow colour).

[image: Shape]

I wish the main body of this svg to have red height, but these spikes should look like spikes from the side (showed it as a blue line). Hope it's clear what I mean. Got no idea of how to do it right.

[image: Desired effect]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out.

1. Import SVG
2. Convert to mesh
3. Edit mode > Faces > A > Extrude
4. Select spike's edge > Select Proportional Editing on the top of the viewport > Connected only
5. Change size of this edge in Z axis